# Simple step form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple step form with 4 steps. I created `i = 1` to control the current step, than inside the `click` function, I incremented `i++` for the next click event shows the next step:

```
var i = 1;

  if (i <= 4 ) {
    $('.step' + i).each(function(){
      $(this).find('a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        i++;

        $('.step' + i).animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
      });
    });
  };
```

As you can see, I use `.each` and `click` event to get the current `<a>` clicked, but it not working. Some help would be appreciated.

EDIT-------

Js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gtsjhe1y/

Comment: Provide some `html` too!!

Comment: Try creating a JSFiddle, it's not obvious at all what you're doing or what's not working.

Comment: Why is it not working? What part specifically?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao , @brso05 , @aquinas , @JaredT I posted a jsfiddle. Looks like `i++` isn't refreshing `i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to change this line `$('.step').each(function(){...`

```
var i = 1;

if (i <= 4 ) {
$('.step').each(function(){
  $(this).find('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    i++;
    $('.step' + i).animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
   });
 });
};
```

The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/n2vcn8tk/) example.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsfiddle.net/gtsjhe1y/2/
It is not finding it right. try this.

```
$(this).parent().find('a').on('click', function(e){
```

Answer (score 1):

To the moment when the button is pressed, value of the variable "i" will be equal 4. For example, you can wrap your bind to anonymous function and pass "i" as it's argument, some like that:

```
$('.step' + i).each(function(){
  (function(i){
     $(this).find('a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       $('.step' + i).animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
     });
  })(i++);
});
```

Comment: I've tried your code but unfortunately it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/gtsjhe1y/4/

Answer (score 1):

you code is doing this :
1- i=1
2- if i<4 this condition will run ONCE as it is not in loop or in function
3- $('.step' + i) where i = 1 so this will return just One value step1 element
4- .each  will run One time as it is working on one element step1
Note: so the ".on" you are doing will bind only step1 link not else elements
5- inside you callback for on click "which on step1 only" i++ incrementing i value.

so next time to click link in step1 will show next element.

so the other links not linked to "on click" and if you click it will refresh page